# Performing left join on two tables where one is a subset of another

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi i am trying to perform left join on two tables t1 and t2, please note that t2 is a subset of t1 but contains a column called 'category' that i want to be in the resultant table. Both the tables contain id as the primary key and i want to take the values for column 'category' in t2 and id values from t1. My code is as follows

```
create table new_table as
select t1.id,t2.category
from xyz as t1 left join abc as t2
on t1.id=t2.id
```

for some reason when i limit the result to 100 using limit 100 with the above query, i get the results but when i am trying to do it for all the data the query never shows any result and is in the execution mode only.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: it just takes longer then you tried to wait. add some where condition to cut off the result, or otherwise reduce amount of data. or just wait for it to complete

Comment: Thanks mate..that worked well..